# How to communicate well to parents of my music students

Tags: teaching, lessons

I have an introverted and a bit shy yet quirky young personality, but with my students I'm a confident private music teacher. However, with parents, I'm somewhat fearful to say the wrong thing.  So I have been avoiding to talk with parents.  **I would appreciate tips or verbiage to say to parents that are clear, professional, and gives a great impression.**

I realize I need to work on my communication skills when the time comes to talk to parents after the lessons, because I have been avoiding it a much as I can since my anxiety tends to show.   **Are there any tips to be brave in overcoming my anxiety so that I can finally be great at communication?** I think my issue is overthinking.  My speech is ok but I just need a lot more confidence.

Comment: This isn't the site for that, however https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ might be.

Comment: It's true, this isn't really a musical issue, but I have a lot of thoughts. I encourage you to rack up the 20 points and ask in the [chat channel](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room). (Preview of my thoughts: 1) own your strengths and challenges, and be open about them if possible, and 2) written communication is great for professionalism anyway.)  I think you can get some points by taking the [tour](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour)?, or try looking for some old questions that you know the answer to. 20 points is just two up-votes.

Comment: Tell it like it is! Some parents are precious, but they're often the ones who need to know the truth about their offspring, and sometimes the truth isn't what they want to hear, even if it's true. Be realistic, and straight from the shoulder, you may lose some students due to this, but is that really a great loss..? And be as positive as is realistic...

Comment: I second both comments about using our chat room and/or the interpersonal SE. But for the purposes of this site, you might focus on a specific music-related issue about which you'd like to better communicate with parents.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about interpersonal skills, not music.

Comment: Hi. Interpersonal skills mod here, this question should *not* be on that site either, not as-is at least! Take a look at it's [help center](https://ips.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it specifically lists questions asking for 'what to say' (verbiage) as off-topic for example. And it's not a site for general 'tips' on what to do, it's there if you have questions about a specific interpersonal skill.

Comment: Congrats on passing 20! I voted to close this question but put my thoughts in the chat channel.